# Change individual values based on total or %

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, sum

[image]

Ability to adjust the total budget at the bottom OR adjust the brand/spend share % for each row OR put in absolute spends

I have two plans in my data. Plan A and Plan B. Plan B is pre-populated with Plan A. The User can either adjust the total budget at the bottom OR adjust the brand/spend share % for each row OR put in absolute spends.

When I tried using a formula, it threw an error saying there are too many circular references.

I then tried using VBA, I was able to get to the part where, when I modify the total, it will change my individual values accordingly and vice versa. I now also want to be able to modify the brand share % and the spend share % to adjust the values.

Here is my current code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim TotalCell As Range
    Dim Total As Double
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim RowOffset As Long
    
    ' Define the range for the total cell
    Set TotalCell = Range("B11")
    
    ' Check if the changed cell is the total cell
    If Not Intersect(Target, TotalCell) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Total = TotalCell.Value
        
        ' Update individual cells based on the changed total value
        For Each Cell In Range("B3:B10")
            ' Determine the row offset to refer to the corresponding cell in column C
            RowOffset = Cell.Row - Range("B3").Row + 1 ' Offset +1 to refer to C3 when in B3
            
            ' Modify the formula to refer to the corresponding cell in column C
            Cell.Formula = "=IF(" & TotalCell.Address & "=0,0," & TotalCell.Address & "*($C$" & RowOffset + 2 & "/SUM($C$3:$C$10)))"
        Next Cell
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Else
        ' Update the total cell if any of the individual cells are changed
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Total = WorksheetFunction.SUM(Range("B3:B10"))
        TotalCell.Value = Total
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't explained how the calculations should be performed. You also haven't asked us a questions that specifically asks for the help you need. You should read [ask].

Comment: @Enigmativity. Thanks for the feedback. This being my first post, messed it up. I have edited the question and updated my current status.

Comment: I have voted to re-open.